# Rewriting an "exponential" of equations as a function of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to rewrite the equation below in the form f(x)=...
Any help is appreciated; I know this is kind of random and not very applicable.

$\left(x-a\right)^{\left(y-b\right)}=\left(y-c\right)^{\left(x-d\right)}+n$

Note: a, b, c, d, and n are all constants

Yes, I know that it's really not a function of x, but like how a quadratic can be inverted if you split it into 2 pieces, my problem might also have a solution.

Comment: Are you asking how to solve for $y$? Not easy, even if $n=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the best known function designed for this problem is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  However, from experience, I know the Lambert W function cannot solve this equation for $y$ or $x$.

If it were able to solve for $x/y$, we'd very likely have $n=0$, $a=d$, and $b=c$.  Else the problem very likely cannot be solved.

Secondly, the best solution you could get is probably a numerical method.

For example, if you tell me $x=0$, I can attempt to give you the decimal value of $y$.  (probably will be needing $a,b,c,d$)

One method, called fixed-point iteration, can work here.

$$y_{n+1}=c+\left((x-a)^{y_n-b}-n\right)^{\frac1{x-d}}$$

$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$

For example, if we are given $x=0$ and guess $y\approx0$, then

$$y_1=c+\left((0-a)^{0-b}-n\right)^{\frac1{x-d}}$$

After we calculate what that is, repeat by plugging that new value of $y_n$ in the algorithm.

This is really the only method I know of that could work here since we can't isolate $x/y$.